# Application doesn't change orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, orientation, screen-orientation

I have an application with a tabbar in which i want to detect interface orientation.

I have set in info.plist the supported orientations.
This is my main interface declaration:

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate> {
   ...
}
```

This is in the implementation of MyAppDelegate:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
        return NO;
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
        return YES;
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait)
        return YES;
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
        return NO;
    }
```

and in the necessary view where i'm trying to detect the orientation change, I'm calling these methods:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
```

and

```
- (void)didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation;
```

I have set NSLog prints in these methods, an none of them is registering any changes. Not even in the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method.

Can anyone please help me? what I'm i doing wrong? 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` is a method you have to implement in your view controllers, not in your app delegate. For a tab bar app to rotate, all child controllers of the tab bar controller have to return `YES` for the requested interface orientation.

Likewise, `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` are to be implemented in the *view controller*, not in the *view* as you say you do.

Comment: Thank you, Ole Begemann. the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation method sould be implemented in all view controllers for the orientation to work. I got it working. But now the problem is that all of the tabs are rotating (i have 3 of them), i need to rotate only the second one. 

If you help me with this, you got a beer :) 

Anyway, thanks again. Helped me out alot!

Comment: Try returning `YES` or `NO` (in all view controllers) from that method depending on which tab is currently visible.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
```

method has to be implemented in your viewController, not in the appdelegate